# How to do a Map side full outer join in Apache Crunch ( Join type FULL_OUTER_JOIN not supported by MapsideJoinStrategy )

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-crunch

Hi i am trying to do a mapside join in crunch using MapsideJoinStrategy class. It is working fine for inner join but it gives this error for full outer join :" Join type FULL_OUTER_JOIN not supported by MapsideJoinStrategy"

Answer (score 0):

[MapsideJoinStrategy](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.11.0/org/apache/crunch/lib/join/MapsideJoinStrategy.html) can not perform RIGHT_OUTER_JOIN and so FULL_OUTER_JOIN. It is impossible by design. Whole work happens in mappers (no reduce phase). Since there can be more than one mapper it is not possible to determine which key from right-side will not have matching key on left-side, because single mapper will not see whole left-side data.

For FULL_OUTER_JOIN use [DefaultJoinStrategy](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.11.0/org/apache/crunch/lib/join/DefaultJoinStrategy.html).

I've extended [BloomFilterJoinStrategy](https://crunch.apache.org/apidocs/0.11.0/org/apache/crunch/lib/join/BloomFilterJoinStrategy.html) to suport all join types. [Here](https://github.com/apache/crunch/pull/9/files) is pull request @ GitHub.